# Unable to start Appium server programmatically

Tags: eclipse, appium

I am trying to start the Appium server using Appium service builder but am getting the following error. I tried everything but still get the error.

```
AppiumTest
io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException: The local appium server has not been started. The given Node.js executable: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe Arguments: [C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js, --port, 4723, --address, 127.0.0.1] 

    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.start(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:191)
```

```
package MahiyarAutomation;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.options.UiAutomator2Options;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

public class AppiumBasics {

    @Test
    public void AppiumTest() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        AppiumDriverLocalService service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\mahiyarwadia\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
        .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").usingPort(4723).build();
        service.start();        
                
        UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
        options.setDeviceName ("MahiyarPhone");
        options.setApp ("//Users//mahiyarwadia//eclipse-workspace//Appium//src//test//java//resources//ApiDemos-debug.apk");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following?

```java
AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
        .withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\mahiyarwadia\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
        .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
        .usingPort(4723);
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
service.start();
```

If it still does not work:

- Are you able to start the server via the GUI or command line?
- Is the Appium path correct?